# One product customized for multiple brands- any good examples?

Tags: gui-design, design, visual-design, branding, examples

We are working on the design of a healthcare app. The company that I work for owns multiple brands that operate within the same industry and similar range of products. A few reasons why there are so many brands:

- price differentiation of the products
- popularity of brands varies on different markets (historically)
- clinics that are used to specific brand, etc.

Within our UX department we are sure that creating separate apps with their own information architecture, navigation, interactions, etc would be an overkill. We would like to differentiate the apps on the outer UI layer (colours, fonts, icons, buttons, images etc.)

Do you know any good examples of the companies that have achieved brand differentiation on this level? We need some good examples of websites, apps or other digital solutions where the core stays the same but the products look very much different because of the visual layer.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Some good examples in the retail sector that I can think of offhand are:

- Gap (Gap, Old Navy, Banana Republic)
- Nike (Nike, Converse, Hurleys)
- Carters (Carters, Osh Kosh)

These sites maintain one general navigation scheme among all the sites, and they all are accessible from a top navigation.